# Biholomorphic leads to harmonic?

Tags: functional-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

> **Exercise:**
> Find a biholomorphic mapping from the domain $\Omega = \{z \in \mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\} : 0 < \operatorname{arg} z < \frac{3\pi}{2}\}$ onto the strip $0 < \operatorname{Im} z < 1$. Use this to find a bounded harmonic function $u: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with boundary value $u = 0$ on $\operatorname{arg} z = 0$ and boundary value $u = 1$ on $\operatorname{arg}z= \frac{3 \pi}2$.

The biholomorphic mapping I found is: $z \mapsto \frac 2 {3 \pi} \ln(z)$. But how can I use this to finish the task? My idea was to just use the imaginary part of the biholomorphic mapping because that is bounded. But that wouldn't be harmonic. What is the solution to this?

Comment: Both the real and the imaginary part of a holomorphic function *are* harmonic.